# Missing walls in Cura after slicing

Tags: creality-ender-3, ultimaker-cura, blender

I designed some line art figure in Blender using several Bezier Curves, converted them all to Meshes, joined them to one Mesh and converted it back to a Curve.
Then I extracted the curve and set a depth and at the end I saved it as a STL file.

Now in Cura (5.2.2.2) using the standard settings I have the following struggle:

When opening up the STL everything seems normal and as designed:

[image: Before slicing]

But after slicing some lines/walls are ignored:

[image: After slicing]

Judging by the preview visualization and time those inner structures disappear.

Do you know how to correct by tweaking the Cura settings?

I think the problem comes from the Blender Project due to the multiple converting and joining process but maybe I can save the current model instead of starting over.

Comment: Are you sure that the problem isn't caused by Blender, Blender is notoriously famous for creating incorrect models (inverted normals, non-manifold structures, etc.). You need to get your STL through a mesh fixer first, if the problem still persists, there may be a different issue at hand.

Comment: Blender is however *way* better than SketchUp...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suspected the error came from the Blender project. I tried using only Bezier curves and after joining and extruding the exported STL file behaves as expected.